# Extract first element of calculated JSONpath response

Tags: mysql, json, jsonpath

If I have the following JSON data:

```
{
  "providers": {
    "abc": {
      "provider": "foo",
      "token": "abc123"
    },
    "def": {
      "provider": "bar",
      "token": "def567"
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to find a JSON path that returns the token of the "first" provider, i.e. `abc123`.  The problem comes in finding the "first", since `providers` is an object, not an array.

I thought I could start with `$.providers.*` which returns the following array:

```
[
  {
    "provider": "foo",
    "token": "abc123"
  },
  {
    "provider": "bar",
    "token": "def567"
  }
]
```

But I can't seem to do anything with that array.  e.g. `$.providers.*[0]` doesn't work.

Is what I'm asking for possible? (If it matters, I'm using MySQL for this, although I'm looking for a general JSONPath solution.)

Comment: What your expected result?

Comment: What about this? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4tuZLkgdM8C7diD1aVciUj/0 you need to use delivered tables to parse it out.

Comment: The expected result would be `abc123`.

Comment: i answerd with a update on mine example which are the output "abc123" @Colin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it like this (using MySQL 5.7, which is why I don't have the `->>` syntax):

```
SET @j = '{
  "providers": {
    "abc": {
      "provider": "foo",
      "token": "abc123"
    },
    "def": {
      "provider": "bar",
      "token": "def567"
    }
  }
}';



SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(
  JSON_EXTRACT(
    JSON_EXTRACT(@j, "$.providers.*"),
    "$[0].token"
  )
) AS token;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use delivered tables/subqueries to parse out the part you need.

> Yes, except I don't know that abc is the first provider.

This parses out the first provider element..

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 *
 , records_json_array.json_array->'$[0].token'
FROM (

SELECT 
 records.json->'$.providers.*' AS json_array
FROM (

SELECT 
 '{
  "providers": {
    "abc": {
      "provider": "foo",
      "token": "abc123"
    },
    "def": {
      "provider": "bar",
      "token": "def567"
    }
  }
}' AS json
FROM 
 DUAL
) AS records

) AS records_json_array
```

**Result**

```
| json_array                                                                       | records_json_array.json_array->'$[0].token' |
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | ---------------------------------------------- |
| [{"token": "abc123", "provider": "foo"}, {"token": "def567", "provider": "bar"}] | "abc123"                                       |
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4tuZLkgdM8C7diD1aVciUj/1)

Comment: Upvote because it works, although adding that many levels of subqueries is going to get unmanageable fairly quickly, I'd think.  Especially if you want to select the JSON data along with other data from a table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select doc->>"$.providers.abc.provider" from x1;
+----------------------------------+
| doc->>"$.providers.abc.provider" |
+----------------------------------+
| foo                              |
+----------------------------------+
```

1 row in set (0.0008 sec)

Your path is providers.abc.provider

Comment: Yes, except I don't know that `abc` is the first provider.

Comment: It would be easier to traverse an array here or use something like the following and just process the first entry.select doc->>"$.providers.*.provider" from x1;
+--------------------------------+
| doc->>"$.providers.*.provider" |
+--------------------------------+
| ["foo", "bar"]                 |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.0004 sec)